# ng-grid is not able to show the column data

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

The following plnkr shows the issue that I am facing.

[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/b3k6uKnKcNqEsK5SOyb1?p=info)

My controller is as follows. I'm expecting the columnA, columnB to show up in the grid but it does not.

```
   var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);
   app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
       $scope.gridOptions = {
           data: 'myData',
           columnDefs: [{ field: "key", width: 120, pinned: true },
                       { field: "a-b-c", width: 120 },
                       { field: "d-e-f", width: 120 }]
       };
       $scope.myData = [
         {
           'key':"SomeKey",
           'a-b-c':"columnaA",
           'd-e-f':"columnB"
         }];
   });
```

When run, both the columns with '-' in their name show 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The minus signs between the key values are not valid. You could try this

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.myData = [{
        'key':'SomeKey',
        'abc':'columnaA',
        'def':'columnB'
      }];

    $scope.gridOptions = {
        data: 'myData',
        columnDefs: [{ field: 'key', width: 120, pinned: true },
                    { field: 'abc', displayName: 'a-b-c', width: 120 },
                    { field: 'def', displayName: 'd-e-f', width: 120 }]
    };

});
```

Comment: Thank you. I should have studied a bit more.